# What is wrong with the performance?

Tags: c#, java, .net

I created an application ( Creating up to 1,00,000 files in a folder )  with 2 different languages ( C#.Net & JAva ) with file concepts and its best methods.

The Application that I created with .NET takes just 3 seconds to create all the files. At the same time, with Java, it takes 15 seconds.

Why is it so ?

Comment: And what is the purpose of this test? Having 1M files in a folder is problematic anyway.

Comment: Have you implemented the same algorithm in both applications?

Comment: no...this is for testing and in future like this apps can be done in best performance language...

Comment: yes..i implemented the same alg in both..

Comment: The question is more than a bit vague ("with file concepts and its best methods" does not really tell much) and it's unclear what kind of answer is expected.

Comment: "C#.Net" and ".NET" are not programming languages. Try it with code written in C# and Java in a unix-like environment (mono), it might look different.

Comment: are you going to base every question you ask around the principle that .net is better than java?

Comment: @Pharabus, If u know the solution give here, otherwise don't give useless comments..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i think the bottleneck is the FileSystem. Creating 1Mio files in a folder can really stress the HDD and/or the MFT table. Also there could step in some I/O caches which are independent from the application.

Thus leading to different result depending in which order you start your applications or if there are any other application or services trying to access the hard-drive.

So at last i can just say a I/O stress test is a really bad performance indicator for the used programming language.

Comment: Any I/O stress testing needs to be done hundreds of times, and the average needs to be used. And then, in that case, you must treat the number as an average, not a hard number.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how each one was implemented.  If you show us how you implemented them both, we might be able to help you better.

Their runtime's are different as well, which always plays a role in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the reason lies in the fact that Java is designed as a generic platform language, while .NET is targeted specifically towards Windows. .NET is usually preferable if you want to work with windows/Microsoft specific things.

Comment: I think that woul dbe your best guess, C# was targeted specifically to windows and made by the same company. They'll have this smoothed out just bit faster. Yu should try writing maybe 1,000 non trivial files where you actually write data. Could very well be that the overhead is just in creating the files, not writing to them.